# JavaScript : Matcher error: received value must be a function

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, jestjs, ts-jest

My questions appear to be duplicates of other questions on stackoverflow. I tried every single solution, but none of them worked.

I have a [sns lambda function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sns.html) which return void. I want to throw an error if the orderId does not exist.

When run the test suite. I am getting this error:

```
Matcher error: received value must be a function

Received has value: undefined
```

**Here is my function**

```js
const parseOrdersFromSns = (event: SNSEvent): Payload[] => {
  try {
    return event.Records.flatMap((r) => JSON.parse(r.Sns.Message));
  } catch (error) {
    Log.error("New order from SNS failed at parsing orders", { event }, error);
    return [];
  }
};
export const handlerFn = async (event: SNSEvent): Promise<void> => {
  const orders = parseOrdersFromSns(event);

  if (orders.length === 0) return;

  const existingOrders = await Promise.all(
    orders.map(
      async (o) => await findOrderStateNode(tagOrderStateId(o.orderId))
    )
  );

  console.log({ orders });

  if (!existingOrders) {
    orders.forEach((o) => {
      throw new Error(
        `Failed to get exisiting order with this orderId: ${o.orderId}`
      );
    });
    
    // other code staff if there is existing order
  }
};
```

**Here is my test suite function where I am passing random orderId which is not legit. So, I am expecting error.**

```js
describe('Making an order by random uuid', () => {
  integrationTest('should throw an error', async () => {
    const order = {
      orderId: '90073f29-d0df-4eca-b93d-ba1cce0d950a',
      roundName,
      startTime,
    }

    const event = {
      Records: [
        {
          Sns: {
            Message: JSON.stringify([order]),
          },
        },
      ],
    } as SNSEvent

// snsListen is my lambda function 

    expect(await snsListen(event)).toThrowError(
      `Failed to get exisiting order with this orderId: ${order.orderId}`,
    )
  })
})
```

Comment: Try something like this: `await expect(snsListen(event)).rejects.toThrow()`.

Comment: First I am sorry and second Thank you for your answer. You gave me correct answer.